# How to show/hide on geo map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick, show-hide, geo

So far I have finally craeted a geo map that contains nodes with lines connecting them. All the nodes have holder ID's and parent companies. However I want a function where you can double click on node and it'll only show the node selected and the nodes it's connected too. I don't know how to do this because I don't know how to connect the lines I created to the nodes. I recreated my example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GarrettUK/x9058g8s/2/. Feel free to ask any questions and thank you in advance!

**The holderID is the company and the parentCompany is the node that owns the node selected:**

```
name: 'Tesco',
radius: 6,
fillKey: 'Negative',
holderID: 2,
parentCompany: 1,
balance: '$132393',
date: '11/07/2005',
latitude: 48.632909,
longitude: 35.024414
```

Comment: Would you like to select connection lines or just connected nodes or both?

Comment: Both. So when you select a node... it shows the lines and nodes it's relating too and hides the nodes and lines it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the `nodes` and `links` widh D3.js:

```
var bnodes = d3.selectAll('.datamaps-bubble');
var blinks = d3.selectAll('.datamaps-arc');
```

Then you could compute additional info to perform the selection of nodes and links more efficient on double click, e.g.:

```
blinks.each(function(dl, il) {
    bnodes.each(function(d,i) {
        if (dl.origin.latitude == d.latitude) {
            dl.origin.holderID = d.holderID;
        } else if (dl.destination.longitude == d.longitude) {
            dl.destination.holderID = d.holderID;
        }
    })
});
```

Then on double click `event` show only the linked nodes and links:

```
bnodes.on('dblclick', function(d, i) {
    blinks.classed('hide', true);
    bnodes.classed('hide', true);

    connectedNodes = [d.holderID];

    blinks.filter(function(dl,il) {
        if (dl.origin.holderID == d.holderID) {
            connectedNodes.push(dl.destination.holderID);
            return true;
        } else if (dl.destination.holderID == d.holderID) {
            connectedNodes.push(dl.origin.holderID);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }).classed('hide', false);

    bnodes.filter(function(dd,ii) {
        return connectedNodes.indexOf(dd.holderID) > -1;
    }).classed('hide', false);
});
```

And finally here is Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x9058g8s/5/ and snippet:

```js
//creating the map
var map = new Datamap({
    element: document.getElementById('map'),
    scope: 'world',
    geographyConfig: {
        popupOnHover: false,
        highlightOnHover: false
    },
    fills: {
        //node colour
        'Positive': '#007D1C',
        'Negative': '#A51000',
        //map colour
        defaultFill: '#9AAEBF',
    },
    arcConfig: {
        strokeColor: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 10,
        arcSharpness: 1,
        animationSpeed: 600
    },
});

var nodes = [{
    name: 'LRZ',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Positive',
    holderID: 1,
    parentCompany: 0,
    balance: '$10032393',
    date: '17/07/2015',
    latitude: 51.727028,
    longitude: -0.395508
},
{
    name: 'Tesco',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Negative',
    holderID: 2,
    parentCompany: 1,
    balance: '$132393',
    date: '11/07/2005',
    latitude: 48.632909,
    longitude: 35.024414
},
{
    name: 'Apple',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Positive',
    holderID: 3,
    parentCompany: 1,
    balance: '$100393',
    date: '01/03/2045',
    latitude: 37.244200,
    longitude: -115.815167
},
{
    name: 'BP',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Negative',
    holderID: 4,
    parentCompany: 1,
    balance: '$10032393',
    date: '17/07/2015',
    latitude: 62.955223,
    longitude: 109.555664
},
{
    name: 'Polycom',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Negative',
    holderID: 5,
    parentCompany: 2,
    balance: '$10032393',
    date: '17/07/2015',
    latitude: 62.955223,
    longitude: 109.555664
},
{
    name: 'Nike',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Negative',
    holderID: 6,
    parentCompany: 0,
    balance: '$10032393',
    date: '17/07/2015',
    latitude: -25.799891,
    longitude: 142.207031
},
{
    name: 'HTC',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Positive',
    holderID: 7,
    parentCompany: 3,
    balance: '$10032393',
    date: '17/07/2015',
    latitude: -3.513421,
    longitude: 24.082031
},
{
    name: 'Microsoft',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Positive',
    holderID: 8,
    parentCompany: 4,
    balance: '$10032393',
    date: '17/07/2015',
    latitude: -12.554564,
    longitude: -43.769531
},
{
    name: 'HP',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Negative',
    holderID: 9,
    parentCompany: 4,
    balance: '$10032393',
    date: '17/07/2015',
    latitude: 52.696361,
    longitude: -93.339844
},
{
    name: 'Poundland',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Negative',
    holderID: 10,
    parentCompany: 4,
    balance: '$10032393',
    date: '17/07/2015',
    latitude: 7.710992,
    longitude: -5.097656
},
{
    name: 'BBC',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Positive',
    holderID: 11,
    parentCompany: 6,
    balance: '$10032393',
    date: '17/07/2015',
    latitude: 71.187754,
    longitude: -36.035156
},
{
    name: 'Sony',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Negative',
    holderID: 12,
    parentCompany: 6,
    balance: '$10032393',
    date: '17/07/2015',
    latitude: 22.268764,
    longitude: 78.574219
},
{
    name: 'LG',
    radius: 6,
    fillKey: 'Positive',
    holderID: 13,
    parentCompany: 9,
    balance: '$10032393',
    date: '17/07/2015',
    latitude: 65.072130,
    longitude: 14.238281
}
];

var arcs = [
  //red lines
  {
    origin: {
      latitude: 48.632909,
      longitude: 35.024414
    },
    destination: {
      latitude: 51.727028,
      longitude: -0.395508
    },
  },
  {
    origin: {
      latitude: 37.244200,
      longitude: -115.815167
    },
    destination: {
      latitude: 51.727028,
      longitude: -0.395508
    },
  },
  {
    origin: {
      latitude: 62.955223,
      longitude: 109.555664
    },
    destination: {
      latitude: 51.727028,
      longitude: -0.395508
    },
  },
  {
    origin: {
      latitude: 48.632909,
      longitude: 35.024414
    },
    destination: {
      latitude: 62.955223,
      longitude: 109.555664
    },
  },
  {
    origin: {
      latitude: 37.244200,
      longitude: -115.815167
    },
    destination: {
      latitude: -3.513421,
      longitude: 24.082031
    },
  },
  {
    origin: {
      latitude: -12.554564,
      longitude: -43.769531
    },
    destination: {
      latitude: 62.955223,
      longitude: 109.555664
    },
  },
  {
    origin: {
      latitude: 52.696361,
      longitude: -93.339844
    },
    destination: {
      latitude: 62.955223,
      longitude: 109.555664
    },
  },
  {
    origin: {
      latitude: 7.710992,
      longitude: -5.097656
    },
    destination: {
      latitude: 62.955223,
      longitude: 109.555664
    },
  },
  {
    origin: {
      latitude: 71.187754,
      longitude: -36.035156
    },
    destination: {
      latitude: -25.799891,
      longitude: 142.207031
    },
  },
  {
    origin: {
      latitude: 22.268764,
      longitude: 78.574219
    },
    destination: {
      latitude: -25.799891,
      longitude: 142.207031
    },
  },
  {
    origin: {
      latitude: 65.072130,
      longitude: 14.238281
    },
    destination: {
      latitude: 52.696361,
      longitude: -93.339844
    },
  },
];
map.arc(arcs,  {strokeWidth: 1, arcSharpness: 1.4});

//draw bubbles for nodes
map.bubbles(nodes, {
    popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
        return ['<div class="hoverinfo">' + 'Name: ' + data.name,
            '<br/>HolderID: ' + data.holderID,
            '<br/>Balance: ' + data.balance + '',
            '<br/>Date: ' + data.date + '',
            '</div>'
        ].join('');
    }
});

var bnodes = d3.selectAll('.datamaps-bubble');
var blinks = d3.selectAll('.datamaps-arc');
blinks.each(function(dl, il) {
    bnodes.each(function(d,i) {
        if (dl.origin.latitude == d.latitude) {
            dl.origin.holderID = d.holderID;
        } else if (dl.destination.longitude == d.longitude) {
            dl.destination.holderID = d.holderID;
        }
    })
});

bnodes.on('dblclick', function(d, i) {
    blinks.classed('hide', true);
    bnodes.classed('hide', true);
    
    connectedNodes = [d.holderID];
    
    blinks.filter(function(dl,il) {
        if (dl.origin.holderID == d.holderID) {
            connectedNodes.push(dl.destination.holderID);
            return true;
        } else if (dl.destination.holderID == d.holderID) {
            connectedNodes.push(dl.origin.holderID);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }).classed('hide', false);

    bnodes.filter(function(dd,ii) {
        return connectedNodes.indexOf(dd.holderID) > -1;
    }).classed('hide', false);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #C0D8ED;
}

div#map {
  position: relative;
  width: 99%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -25%;
}

h1 {
  color: #193369;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Intercompany Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>My D3 Node Map</h1>
    <div id="map" style="height:800px"></div>
    <script src="js/icm.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Is there a function that when you have hidden the nodes/lines... to double click again and the map then shows all the nodes/lines again?

Comment: as in if you click anywhere on the map after hiding, they reappear?

Comment: @TheGarrett yeah, it is simple, just call this 2 lines: `blinks.classed('hide', false);` and `bnodes.classed('hide', false);`. I updated jsFiddle and added function `showAllNodesAndLinks` http://jsfiddle.net/x9058g8s/7/. When you double click second time all links and nodes are visible again.

Comment: @TheGarrett and here is when you single click the country on the map: http://jsfiddle.net/x9058g8s/6/

Comment: Thank you, you've been a big help!

Comment: would you know how to do a function hat when you click on a line, 2 more lines appear next to the one you clicked on? I've been trying to re-create this example on the geo map... http://jsfiddle.net/xhpg2ghn/3/